# MYSQL Triggers with an inner join

Tags: mysql, triggers, inner-join

I have 2 tables called users and jobs. I have made a third table which is an inner join of users and jobs called jobPosts. My question is to do with when I insert values into the jobs table that it will also insert into the new jobPosts table. Here is my attached SQL but its failing to work for me.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER trg_jobs_after_insert 
 AFTER INSERT ON jobs
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO jobPost (userID, name, email, phoneNo, location, jobID, 
title, level, dateFrom, dateTo, description) 
SELECT 
     users.name
     , users.email
       , users.phoneNo
         , users.location
     , NEW.jobID
     , NEW.title
     , NEW.level
     , NEW.dateFrom
     , NEW.dateTo
      , NEW.description
  FROM users
  WHERE users.userID= NEW.user.userID;
 END
```

Tables ->

**Jobs Table**:
[image: jobsTable]

**Users Table**:
[image: usersTable]

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: its executing ok, but its not inserting into new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where condition needs to be on `email` instead of `userID`. Also, you are missing `userId` in select for inserting.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER trg_jobs_after_insert 
 AFTER INSERT ON jobs
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jobPost (userID, name, email, phoneNo, location, jobID, 
                       title, level, dateFrom, dateTo, description) 
  SELECT 
     users.userID
     , users.name
     , users.email
     , users.phoneNo
     , users.location
     , NEW.jobID
     , NEW.title
     , NEW.level
     , NEW.dateFrom
     , NEW.dateTo
     , NEW.description
  FROM users
  WHERE users.email = NEW.email;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, however the new.userID I got an error unknown column.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin what is the table structure for `jobs` table

Comment: Can I attache image in comments

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin you can edit the original question and add table structure there

Comment: Attached screengrab of jobstable.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin where do you get userID from ? How is jobId related to userId

Comment: userID from user table and jobID from job table. But email is common in both, should the join be with the email?

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin please also post the table structure for `user`

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin please check the updated answer now. i have changed the where condition to `email`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It was simple in the end up. It is working fine!

Comment: Can i get your help Madhur? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin yes do tell

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin No that will kill the purpose of this post. Please create a new question. You can reference to this question for additonal details

Comment: I have posted the question

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin which ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859884/updating-database-value-from-a-button-with-in-a-list?noredirect=1#comment92635439_52859884

Comment: Have you received this ?

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin yes. But sorry I am actually not so involved with frontend concepts like javascript, jquery etc

Comment: Madhur I think I need help again. Its SQL this time.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin Please post a new question and you can tag me there.

Comment: I cannot post anymore questions unfortunately. I may make another account and tag your name.

Comment: @AdamMcMenamin curious that why you cannot post anymore ? What is the error or restriction message you getting. Anyways, you can post question using new account and just put the question link here in the comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051640/mysql-inner-join-with-after-update-in-table