# MYSQL - Inner Join with AFTER UPDATE in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called jobPosts in my mySQL datbase. I am trying to to insert data into another table (jobRequest) once an update has occurred in my current jobPost table.

Here is my SQL tables & queries.

```
           DELIMITER //
           CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
           trg_jobPost_after_update
           AFTER UPDATE ON jobPost
           FOR EACH ROW
           BEGIN
           INSERT INTO jobRequest (userID, name, email, phoneNo, 
            location, jobID, 
                   title, level, dateFrom, dateTo, description, 
                   jobStatus, emailTeacher, nameTeacher, 
                   locationTeacher, phoneNoTeacher, cv, gardavetting, 
                   linkedin) 
      SELECT 
        jobPost.userID
      ,  jobPost.name
      ,  jobPost.email
      ,  jobPost.phoneNo
      ,  jobPost.location
      ,  jobPost.jobID
      ,  jobPost.title
      ,  jobPost.level
      ,  jobPost.dateFrom
      ,  jobPost.dateTo
      ,  jobPost.description
      , users.nameTeacher
      , users.locationTeacher
      , users.phoneNoTeacher
      , users.cv
      , users.gardavetting
      , users.linkedin
      , NEW.jobStatus
     , NEW.emailTeacher
   FROM jobPost
   WHERE jobPosts.emailTeacher = NEW.emailTeacher;
  END //
  DELIMITER ;
```

Tables -

jobPost table[image]

users Table[image]

[jobRequest Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi24z.png)

Comment: What is the error/issue ? How are jobPost and users table connected ?  What is the foreign key between them ?

Comment: emailTeacher is in both the jobPost table and Users table. The problem is before I apply this trigger the table updates correctly, however when I create the trigger the table does not update

Comment: Isn't the first column `userID` in the `jobPost` table image ?

Comment: It is. But i want to make the inner join based on the emailTeacher?

Comment: What if the `emailTeacher` value does not exist in the `users` table ?

Comment: it does exist though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, it seems that you simply need a `Inner Join` between the `jobPost` and `users` table, on `emailTeacher`.

Also, some columns from `Select` were missing, in comparison to `Insert` clause; I have added them in proper order.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
    trg_jobPost_after_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON jobPost
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN

       -- Check if jobStatus is Updated (then only we Insert) 
       IF ( OLD.jobStatus <> NEW.jobStatus AND 
            OLD.emailTeacher <> NEW.emailTeacher ) THEN 
         INSERT INTO jobRequest (userID, name, email, phoneNo, 
                                 location, jobID, title, level, 
                                 dateFrom, dateTo, description, 
                                 jobStatus, emailTeacher, nameTeacher, 
                                 locationTeacher, phoneNoTeacher, cv, 
                                 gardavetting, linkedin) 
         SELECT 
           jobPost.userID
        ,  jobPost.name
        ,  jobPost.email
        ,  jobPost.phoneNo
        ,  jobPost.location
        ,  jobPost.jobID
        ,  jobPost.title
        ,  jobPost.level
        ,  jobPost.dateFrom
        ,  jobPost.dateTo
        ,  jobPost.description
        ,  NEW.jobStatus 
        ,  NEW.emailTeacher 
        ,  users.nameTeacher 
        , users.locationTeacher
        , users.phoneNoTeacher
        , users.cv
        , users.gardavetting
        , users.linkedin
        FROM jobPost 
        JOIN users ON users.emailTeacher = jobPost.emailTeacher 
        WHERE jobPost.emailTeacher = NEW.emailTeacher;

      END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Madhur, Can you help with a small sql query. Thanks. Please see link ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416674/how-to-avoid-duplicate-rows-after-insert-into-new-table-sql?noredirect=1#comment93707821_53416674