# How to avoid duplicate rows after insert into new table?- SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger in my jobPost table that fires after an update to column jobStatus & emailTeacher. The trigger inserts all rows that match emailTeacher and insert into a new table called jobRequests.

My problem is - When a row is updated, all rows with that SAME emailTeacher inserts into the new table. I would like to only INSERT the affected row that has been updated. I have attached sql below. Thank you. Any help appreciated.

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
trg_jobPost_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON jobPost
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN

   -- Check if jobStatus is Updated (then only we Insert) 
   IF ( OLD.jobStatus <> NEW.jobStatus AND OLD.emailTeacher <> NEW.emailTeacher) THEN 
     INSERT INTO jobRequest (userID, name, email, phoneNo, 
                             location, lat, lng, jobID, title, level, 
                             dateFrom, dateTo, description, 
                             jobStatus, emailTeacher, nameTeacher, 
                             locationTeacher, phoneNoTeacher, cv, 
                             gardavetting, linkedin) 
     SELECT 
       jobPost.userID
    ,  jobPost.name
    ,  jobPost.email
    ,  jobPost.phoneNo
    ,  jobPost.location
    ,  jobPost.lat
    ,  jobPost.lng
    ,  jobPost.jobID
    ,  jobPost.title
    ,  jobPost.level
    ,  jobPost.dateFrom
    ,  jobPost.dateTo
    ,  jobPost.description
    ,  NEW.jobStatus 
    ,  NEW.emailTeacher 
    ,  users.nameTeacher 
    , users.locationTeacher
    , users.phoneNoTeacher
    , users.cv
    , users.gardavetting
    , users.linkedin
    FROM jobPost 
    JOIN users ON users.emailTeacher = jobPost.emailTeacher 
    WHERE jobPost.emailTeacher = NEW.emailTeacher;

  END IF;
```

END

[image: Duplicate of entry]

Comment: Make one column unique, and do INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Column unique in the inserted table or the table that is being updated. Thanks!